# Android - Cannot connect to external IP address over mobile 3G/4G network using sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, port, 4g

Right now, I am writing a server/client program to allow a user to control different parts of their computer from an android phone on the fly. The server runs on the computer and the client runs from the android phone. I am using socket programming to do this, WinSocket on the computer and Android/Java sockets on the phone.

What Works:

1. The server on the computer end works.
2. When on the same wifi network, the client on the phone can send and
   receive commands to/from the server.
3. The server is accessible from outside the local wireless network it is connected to. I
   tested this by using this [open port checking tool](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to send a request
   to the server. The server can successfully receive the request, and
   the port checking website reports that the port I am using is
   properly forwarded.
4. When using an app on my android phone that tests open ports, my
   server gets the connection request over 3G/4G.

Now for my problem. When I try to connect to the server running on the computer from the client on the phone, **when the phone is connected to the internet through 3G or 4G**, the socket does nothing and throws a socket timeout exception, and the server does not receive any connection request from the phone. I don't understand this because, like the 4th thing above, the port checking app I used can get through to my server program, but the code I'll post below doesn't do anything when running on 3G/4G.

```
String hostName = "SERVER_NETWORK_EXTERNAL_IP_HERE";
int port = 58587;
SocketAddress address = new java.net.InetSocketAddress(hostName, port);
sock = new Socket();
sock.connect(address, 5000);
```

The network activity indicator in the status bar at the top of the screen does not report outbound network activity when running this code, however if I am connected to wifi, everything works correctly. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You might consider installing an Android app equivalent to your open port checking tool (e.g., https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sanctuaire.netswisstool -- use Portscan TCP) and see what results you get.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion, I tried that and my server gets the request from the phone when using that app over 3G and 4G (I know my server got the port check request because it crashes each time I try it, lol). I'll update my question.

Comment: Have you made sure you requested the necessary permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have the internet permission in my app. If I didn't, my client would not have been able to contact my server over wifi. Right now, everything works except the socket appears to do nothing when I attempt to connect over the mobile data network. It simply times out without making any attempt to connect to the ip address.

Comment: I had the same issue. Try using `AndroidHttpClient` instead of `DefaultHttpClient`.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be it. I'm not using an HTTP client, I'm using sockets. The last three lines of code in my code example are the bare minimum I can do for connecting to my computer running as a server.

Comment: Kinda old here, but have you properly configured the network on which the server sits? If it's behind a router, you need to set up port forwarding.

Comment: I am facing same problem. Please let me know if anyone have an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to connect 3g clients to the server? I am facing the same problem. Please let me know if you were able to solve this. Reading other threads on SO, I guess NAT is the solution but I am not sure how to start.